# Problems with the rgl package

Tags: r, rgl

I am trying to create a 3D plot using plot3d from the rgl package and the R graph gallery as help: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/3d_scatter_plot.html

I installed rgb and got this error:

```
library(rgl)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgl’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘htmltools’ 0.5.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.0.9001 is required
```

Okay, cool, so I updated htlmtools, prompted to restart and the usual bla bla, only to get this error:

`Error in function (srcref) : unimplemented type (29) in 'eval'`

and the R session aborted.

````
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Ireland.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Ireland.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Ireland.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                     LC_TIME=English_Ireland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] Taxonstand_2.2     pbapply_1.4-3      plot3D_1.3         lemon_0.4.5        gridExtra_2.3      ggspatial_1.1.5   
 [7] circlize_0.4.12    networkD3_0.4      plotrix_3.7-8      broom_0.5.6        RColorBrewer_1.1-2 ggrepel_0.9.1     
[13] ggcharts_0.2.1     sf_0.9-7           parallelDist_0.2.4 geosphere_1.5-10   rangeBuilder_1.5   rgeos_0.5-3       
[19] maptools_1.0-1     rgdal_1.5-12       raster_3.3-7       sp_1.4-2           corrplot_0.84      sjstats_0.18.1    
[25] vegan_2.5-6        lattice_0.20-41    permute_0.9-5      data.table_1.13.6  plyr_1.8.6         reshape2_1.4.4    
[31] janitor_2.0.1      forcats_0.5.0      stringr_1.4.0      dplyr_1.0.0        purrr_0.3.4        readr_1.3.1       
[37] tidyr_1.1.0        tibble_3.0.1       ggplot2_3.3.2      tidyverse_1.3.0    devtools_2.3.2     usethis_2.0.0     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] readxl_1.3.1        backports_1.2.1     igraph_1.2.6        splines_4.0.4       crosstalk_1.1.1     digest_0.6.27      
 [7] htmltools_0.5.0     fansi_0.4.1         magrittr_1.5        memoise_1.1.0       cluster_2.1.0       remotes_2.2.0      
[13] modelr_0.1.8        RcppParallel_5.0.2  prettyunits_1.1.1   colorspace_1.4-1    blob_1.2.1          rvest_0.3.5        
[19] haven_2.3.1         xfun_0.15           tcltk_4.0.4         callr_3.5.1         crayon_1.3.4        jsonlite_1.7.2     
[25] lme4_1.1-26         glue_1.4.1          gtable_0.3.0        emmeans_1.5.4       sjmisc_2.8.6        pkgbuild_1.2.0     
[31] shape_1.4.5         scales_1.1.1        mvtnorm_1.1-1       DBI_1.1.0           Rcpp_1.0.4.6        xtable_1.8-4       
[37] performance_0.7.0   units_0.6-7         foreign_0.8-81      htmlwidgets_1.5.3   httr_1.4.2          ellipsis_0.3.1     
[43] pkgconfig_2.0.3     dbplyr_1.4.4        tidyselect_1.1.0    rlang_0.4.10        effectsize_0.4.4    munsell_0.5.0      
[49] cellranger_1.1.0    tools_4.0.4         cli_2.0.2           generics_0.0.2      sjlabelled_1.1.7    processx_3.4.5     
[55] knitr_1.29          fs_1.4.2            nlme_3.1-152        xml2_1.3.2          compiler_4.0.4      rstudioapi_0.11    
[61] e1071_1.7-4         testthat_2.3.2      reprex_0.3.0        statmod_1.4.35      stringi_1.4.6       ps_1.3.3           
[67] parameters_0.12.0   desc_1.2.0          Matrix_1.3-2        classInt_0.4-3      nloptr_1.2.2.2      vctrs_0.3.1        
[73] pillar_1.4.4        lifecycle_0.2.0     GlobalOptions_0.1.2 estimability_1.3    insight_0.13.1      patchwork_1.1.1    
[79] R6_2.4.1            KernSmooth_2.23-18  sessioninfo_1.1.1   codetools_0.2-18    boot_1.3-26         MASS_7.3-53        
[85] assertthat_0.2.1    pkgload_1.1.0       rprojroot_1.3-2     withr_2.4.0         mgcv_1.8-33         bayestestR_0.8.2   
[91] parallel_4.0.4      hms_0.5.3           grid_4.0.4          coda_0.19-3         class_7.3-18        minqa_1.2.4        
[97] misc3d_0.9-0        snakecase_0.11.0    lubridate_1.7.9    ```

I have tried running this in plain R, not a markdown document as I was using when the error occurred and encountered the same error. 

Any ideas? Package (inter)dependencies perhaps?
````

Comment: The error message *"but >= 0.5.0.9001 is required"* is clear, and no errors with `rgl` experienced after that are valid. Reloading packages that are loaded can be problematic (esp with compiled code). Since `htmltools` has compiled DLLs, you need to close and restart R (fresh, no `.Rdata` files), and then install the relevant version of `htmltools` (the CRAN version should meet that restriction), then re-attempt installation of `rgl`.

Comment: Thanks, that did it, didn't know R could be so "extra" and need a new session with no .Rdata etc. etc. Wanna add that as an answer?

Comment: It's a common thing for any programming language: after you dynamically link a DLL, unlinking it and linking a newer version can be problematic. I'm sure other languages have ways to make it work, but it is riddled with problems and fail-modes. R is perhaps not as good at this as others, but it is far from an "easy" thing. (The need to avoid `.Rdata` files is that starting R with an `.Rdata` file in the directory can cause packages to be loaded inadvertently. It's a precaution I always take when making this recommendation ... which appears to be weekly these days.)

Comment: There have recently been several updates to packages commonly used in ecological statistics and many colleagues are struggling with similar issues. Times are a-changing and so is R ;).